# Swipe using mobile touchscreen

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am new to game development, i am trying to to change my code to mobile touch. I tried to change the flowing code to make workable for mobile touchscreen unfortunately failed. can you help me how can I make flowing code for mobile?
Here is the code.

```
    Vector2 newPos;
    bool canMove = true;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        newPos = transform.position;
    }

private void Update()
    {
        if (canMove)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                newPos.x += 1.4f;
                transform.position = newPos;                
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            {
                newPos.x -= 1.4f;
                transform.position = newPos;
                    
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && canMove)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.down * speed);
            canMove = false;
        }
        Vector2 clampPos = transform.position;
        clampPos.x = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -2.1f, 2.1f);
        transform.position = clampPos;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by failed?

Comment: i try some swipe with mobile touch, but it didn't work like what i want.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: @younesalaoui  please mention what is actual and expected behaviour

Comment: can you tell me what more details i have to mention, i use this code to move gameobject left and right, it's working good, i want it to work on mobile, so i have to swtich it to mobile input, i don't know how to do it.

Comment: what i want to do is, when player put his finger he can move the ball left and right, here i want use (first IF condition) see the code. and when he raises his finger i want use "Second IF condition"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Canvas with a screen wide transparent Image component inside.

Use [OnPointerDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html) and [OnDrag](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IDragHandler.html) event functions to catch finger movement on this image. Just make your class implement IPointerDownHandler and IDragHandler interfaces and use PointerEventData args properties to get delta or current position.

You can use the code below. Add it to the screen wide image and assign your Ridigbody2d and transform in inspector.

```
public class Movement: MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IDragHandler
{
    public Rigidbody2d rb;

    public float maxSpeed = 10f;
    public float sensitivity = 0.1f;
    public float xBound = 2.1f;


    Vector3 initialFingerPosition;
    bool canMove = true;

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        initialFingerPosition = pointerEventData.position;
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data)
    {
        if(!canMove)
            return;

        var position = rb.position;
        position += data.delta * sensitivity * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        position.x = Mathf.Clamp(position.x, -xBound, xBound);

        rb.MovePosition(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, i don't need work with something like "if input.touch > 0" then i put code do like what my first code do ?

Comment: what i want to do is, when player put his finger he can move the ball left and right, here i want use (first IF condition) see the code. and when he raises his finger i want use "Second IF condition"

Comment: So, use IPointerUpHandler and IPointerDownHandler interfaces and OnPointerUp and OnPointerDown event function

Comment: You need to know the finger movement info. OnDrag will give you that

Comment: okay i will try that, thank you for your help

Comment: i try that, it didn't work for me, can you please if you have free time change my code to use IPointerUpHandler and IPointerDownHandler interfaces and OnPointerUp and OnPointerDown event function.

Comment: Check the edited answer, I provided the full class code